# The usage of "rob" and "fine"

Tags: prepositions

He robbed a woman just hours earlier.

> He robbed a woman ***of*** her bag.

Why not say "He robbed a woman her bag"?  Why should "of" be used here?

Likewise, it seems that the usage of "fine" is similar to

> He fined the woman $ 100.

Why not say "***He fined the woman of $100***"?

Comment: No reason. It's just an arbitrary requirement imposed by the English language.

Answer (score 1):

Because that's the structure. You always `rob somebody/something OF something`

> [rob](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/rob) - *to steal money or property from a person or place*

So, it's He robbed a woman *of* her bag.

Likewise, you always `fine somebody something FOR something/doing something`

> [fine](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/fine_4) - fine somebody something

So, it could be - He **fined the woman $100** *for* breaking the traffic rule.

Comment: It's usually good practice not to use the word you're defining in the definition. Although, to be fair, it's more of a predicate-argument syntax than a definition. You can also just _rob somebody_, without specifying what it was, a la: _she robbed him_, _I was robbed_, etc. Similarly you can fine someone without specifying the amount: _He was fined_.

Comment: @jimsug No! That's not the OP is concerned about. I think everybody knows that *she robbed him* is a complete sentence. The OP **specifically** asked how/why *preposition* 'of' is used. **And,** I used *it could be* in my last sentence and included the preposition to make the point clearer.

Comment: Yeah, sorry - got carried away with syntax. But my point about definitions stands. Just because something in your answer isn't what the OP asks for specifically, doesn't mean it shouldn't be well-formed.

Comment: @jimsug you again missed it! I specifically typed the standard use of prepositions in 'preformatted text' and did not include them as **definitions.** In fact, if you want *well-formed* sentence, I think everybody will strongly prefer going for the structure defined in OALD. :)

Comment: Okay,using exclamation marks makes you sound defensive. I apologise for thinking that you were defining the words using quote formatting. Clearly, I misunderstood.

Comment: @jimsug that's okay! Such comments also help me recheck my answers so thanks! :)